# JPEG (JPG) file format - Want to store data. Is it possible?

Tags: file, header, format, hex, jpeg

The interesting question here is: 
I want to store in a JPEG file some data (from 1kilo to 1mega). Is that possible without damaging the picture?

A practical example: I have an image in which I want to store 500 kb of text without the jpg file to lose it's property of being an image.

I hope you understand my question.

Comment: If you want it to be accessible by anyone there is a "UserComment" EXIF tag

Comment: Yep, I know, but only 29848 chars are accepted there. I can't store much info in there.

Comment: The spec says any length ... where does 29848 come from?

Comment: Tested. Pasted text until it refused to add. Then charcounter (it seems that the limit is 30000, at least in windows).

Comment: Besides that, when trying to save with that comment, an error that I haven't saw it since I was born. "Error 0x88982F52. No error description available"

Comment: Well that sounds like its a limitation of whatever you pasting it into, you would check this programmatically.

Comment: You should be able to store arbitrary data in your own `APPn` segments. These have limited size, but you should be able to store multiple segments, if needed. See the JFIF spec for more details. Existing JPEG software should just ignore your `APPn` segments.

Comment: @haraldK Thank you for the answer. Useful!